# Group matching key:values in a lists of dictionaries, and put into NEW lists of dictionaries WITHOUT PANDAS

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries. Here's a cut down sample

```
data = [ {u'jid': 2958806, u'tier': u'anim_sweatbox'},
         {u'jid': 2958850, u'tier': u'anim_sweatbox'}, 
         {u'jid': 2959481, u'tier': u'default'} ]
```

They need to be grouped together in different lists if they have a matching tier, like this

```
   data1 = [ {u'jid': 2958806, u'tier': u'anim_sweatbox'}]
   data2 = [ {u'jid': 2958850, u'tier': u'anim_sweatbox'}, 
             {u'jid': 2959481, u'tier': u'default'} ]
```

What seems difficult to me is that the code needs to be able to handle situations with varying sizes of lists that will need to be created, as well as somehow naming and calling these lists.

I'm doing this at work and do not have access to Pandas, and many other libraries.

Comment: Can you explain how what you say is the desired output is grouping lists by matching tiers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will reorganize things based on tiers:

```
result = {}
for d in data:
    k = d['tier']
    if k in result:
        result[k].append(d)
    else:
        result[k] = [d]
```

Comment: It's rather difficult to understand the OP's question based on what his expected output. But he seems to be expecting multiple lists as the result rather than a dictionary.

Comment: That'll work perfectly (and nowhere near as difficult as I'd imaginged). Thanks.

Comment: @RonaldAaronson you're right, but I will just change my code a bit to work with a dictionary instead.

Comment: Add: `result = [v for v in result.values()]` to get a list of lists: `[[{'jid': 2958806, 'tier': 'anim_sweatbox'}, {'jid': 2958850, 'tier': 'anim_sweatbox'}], [{'jid': 2959481, 'tier': 'default'}]]`

Comment: You can assign the values in the dictionary to other variables as necessary; as OP didn't go into detail about that mapping, I didn't address it.

Comment: @RonaldAaronson: Isn't that just `result.values()`?

Comment: And I guess the point is that he does need some way of "naming" the lists. And yes, it would be that (dummy me) for Python 2 or list(result.values()) for Python 3.